# Is there a difference between the statements below?

Tags: python

I was looking at the solution for the Titanic Problem in [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic) and there is a part that it does:

```
data['Cabin'] = data['Cabin'].replace(['A', 'D', 'E', 'T'], 'M')
```

What is the difference between the code above and only:

```
data['Cabin'].replace(['A', 'D', 'E', 'T'], 'M')
```

Comment: What is `data`/`data['Cabin']` exactly…?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html   .replace() returns a new object, it doesn't modify the current one, so to have your dataframe modified you need to reassign it, as you do in the first case.

Comment: one assigns, one doesn't?

Comment: If you are referring to a [Pandas DataFrame replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) then the answer is simple. One replaces it and sets it back to the variable (same as using `inplace=True`) while the other one simply returns it.

Comment: @ArkistarvhKltzuonstev `.replace()` does have an `inplace` option. It's set to `false` by default though.

Answer (score 0):

`data['Cabin'] = data['Cabin'].replace(['A', 'D', 'E', 'T'], 'M')` replaces your 'Cabin' column with a transformed one.

`data['Cabin'].replace(['A', 'D', 'E', 'T'], 'M')` returns you a new Series object (in your case it is a column, I suppose).

So if you will write it the second way, your original dataframe will not change. If you will write it the first way, it will change.

[.replace()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html#pandas.DataFrame.replace) has an attribute `inplace`. It is set to False by default. If you will set it to True, the behaviour of `data['Cabin'].replace(['A', 'D', 'E', 'T'], 'M', inplace=True)` will be equal to `data['Cabin'] = data['Cabin'].replace(['A', 'D', 'E', 'T'], 'M')`

Answer (score 0):

To modify the 'Cabin' column in data Dataframe use:

```
data['Cabin'] = data['Cabin'].replace(['A', 'D', 'E', 'T'], 'M')
```

recommended way is:

```
data['Cabin'].replace(['A', 'D', 'E', 'T'], 'M', inplace=True)
```

Below code will simply return new series. The data DataFrame will not be modified:

```
data['Cabin'].replace(['A', 'D', 'E', 'T'], 'M')
```